# Embed a single react component created with create-react-library into html page

Tags: reactjs

Although there are several questions concerning the (almost) same topic, I wasn't able to get my component showing.
This is what I want to achieve:

I've made a react library using [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library)

When you run this create-react-library in the terminal, boilerplate code is generated and an ExampleComponent component is generated.
I can cd to the example folder and run 'yarn start' to display my component in the browser. It shows this:

[image: this is a screenshot]

Now I want to embed **this single component** into an existing pure HTML page.

My questions are:

- what files of the generated node project should I upload to my server?
- how to show **ExampleComponent** in my HTML page?

Comment: I don't fully get what you mean: you want to upload somewhere the example app to see it running?

Comment: No, I want the ExampleComponent (or the subsequent components I will make) to show up on an HTML page. Just like you would embed a youtube video in a HTML page. I want to create a React library and use it's components in several HTML pages

Comment: So you need a react application (why not the example ones?) that will import and use it.
With create-react-library- you are generating a _library_ not an app, so it can be used or shown on is own. You need an _app_ that use it.
`example` folder is an app.

Comment: I know luca but what I want is use React components in a non react environment like HTML

Comment: Ok, but still: you need a react app that at least render you component and nothing more. So the @nishant answer below if the right one.

Comment: So you MUST have an app to render a component? You can't just render a component in an HTML page?

Comment: An "app" (maybe I used the wrong term) can be just a call to `ReactDOM.render`. You need to have ReactDOM to render React stuff.

Answer (score 4):

In order to upload file on server, you need to have prod build(not necessary but will makes thing light and easy for you).
You can get PROD build by running `npm build`.

Before doing that, make sure your component will be mounted on actual element in your html page. Update the following code
`ReactDOM.render(
  <your component />,
  document.getElementById('<id of your element in your pure html page>')
);`

Now, build your project. A `build/static` folder will be created in your project folder. Upload that to your server and update your index.html as
In head:
`<link href="/static/css/<main css file, actual name can be found in static/css/>" rel="stylesheet">`

In Body:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/<main js name found in static/js/>"></script>`

Comment: Your example is correct. I know that is how it should be done, but I can't accomplish this. I've made my repo public. Could you please try to get it running?
[This is the repo](https://github.com/ahs-mediatheken/web-component-quote.git)

Comment: Sure, will go through it and let you know

Comment: Went through your code. You were trying to use your component as node module. 
So, separated example folder from your app. Build your webcomponent-quote using `npm run-script build`. Then copy pasted your web-component-quote into `node modules` folder of your example app. It worked. Please let me know if you were trying to do something else.

Comment: Thanks Nishant for your help. I can run my component in another react app. That's not the problem. Let me elaborate on the subject a bit more: We have a traditional HTML/Javascript website which is divided into 'parts'. Every part has it's own HTML and javascript code. Eventually, we'll refactor the website into a single page React site. But we want to do that gradually. I want to build each React component and replace it in the original site until all components are finished and can be wrapped into a 'master' React app.

Answer (score 1):

You can make react components without A Build Step, to do you need to add the following to you html page

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know, but I can't get my component displayed. See my reply on @Nishant comment